# Checking the analyticity of a complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, analyticity

This was a question in an assignment that demands the use of [Cauchy's Integral Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) in the questions. The question goes like this:

> Integrate $\displaystyle{g(z)=\frac{e^z}{ze^z-2iz}}$ over $\displaystyle{C:\ \vert z\vert=0.5}$.

**What I tried:**

First, I noted that $\displaystyle{g(z)=\frac{e^z}{z\left(e^z-2i\right)}}$ so I could use the Cauchy's Integral Formula with $z_o=0$ and $\displaystyle{f(z)=\frac{e^z}{e^z-2i}}$. To do so, I have to make sure that $f(z)$ is analytic. So, I proceed like this:

As $z=x+iy$, so
$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{e^{x+iy}}{e^{x+iy}-2i}\\
&=\frac{e^x \cos y+ie^x\sin y}{e^x \cos y+ie^x\sin y-2i}\\
&=1+\frac{2i}{e^x \cos y+ie^x\sin y-2i}\\
&=1+\frac{2i\left(e^x \cos y-ie^x\sin y+2i\right)}{\left(e^x \cos y+ie^x\sin y-2i\right)\left(e^x \cos y-ie^x\sin y+2i\right)}\\
&=1+\frac{2ie^x\cos y+2e^x\sin y-4}{e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2}\\
&=\left[1+\frac{2e^x\sin y-4}{e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2}\right]+i\left[\frac{2e^x\cos y}{e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2}\right]\\
&=u+iv
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$u=1+\frac{2e^x\sin y-4}{e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2}\ \ \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \ \ v=\frac{2e^x\cos y}{e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2}$$
Now according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com),
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}&=\frac{2e^x\sin y}{e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2}-\frac{\left(2e^x\sin y-4\right)\left(2e^x\sin y\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)+2e^{2x}\cos^2y\right)}{\left(e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2\right)^2}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}&=\frac{2e^x\cos y}{e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2}-\frac{\left(2e^x\sin y-4\right)\left(2e^x\cos y\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)-2e^{2x}\sin y\cos y\right)}{\left(e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2\right)^2}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}&=\frac{2e^x\cos y}{e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2}-\frac{2e^x\cos y\left(2e^x\sin y\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)+2e^{2x}\cos^2 y\right)}{\left(e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2\right)^2}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}&=-\frac{2e^x\sin y}{e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2}-\frac{2e^x\cos y\left(2e^x\cos y\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)-2e^{2x}\sin y\cos y\right)}{\left(e^{2x}\cos^2y+\left(e^x\sin y-2\right)^2\right)^2}
\end{align}
$$

*Links for WolframAlpha: [du/dx](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find%20d%2Fdx%281%2B%282e%5Ex%20sin%20y-4%29%2F%28e%5E%282x%29%20%28cos%20y%29%5E2%2B%28e%5Ex%20sin%20y%20-%202%29%5E2%29%29)   [du/dy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find%20d%2Fdy%281%2B%282e%5Ex%20sin%20y-4%29%2F%28e%5E%282x%29%20%28cos%20y%29%5E2%2B%28e%5Ex%20sin%20y%20-%202%29%5E2%29%29)   [dv/dx](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find%20d%2Fdx%28%282e%5Ex%20cos%20y%29%2F%28e%5E%282x%29%20%28cos%20y%29%5E2%2B%28e%5Ex%20sin%20y%20-%202%29%5E2%29%29)   [dv/dy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find%20d%2Fdy%28%282e%5Ex%20cos%20y%29%2F%28e%5E%282x%29%20%28cos%20y%29%5E2%2B%28e%5Ex%20sin%20y%20-%202%29%5E2%29%29)*

Now clearly, these values for $\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$ do not satisfy the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#:%7E:text=In%20the%20field%20of%20complex,sufficient%20condition%20for%20a%20complex).

Did I do anything wrong during the solution? If not, what method should be used to solve the required integral?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: There is no need to try to verify the C-R equations. They will always be satisfied in form by such elementary functions. If you think they aren't then you have made a mistake in the computation. You only have to ensure that $f$ has no singularity in the disk. Specifically: does $e^z = 2i$ have a solution with $|z|\leq \tfrac12$ ?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $f$ defined in $U=D(0,r)$ where $\frac{1}{2}<r<\text{ln}(2)$ then $f(z)=\frac{e^z}{e^z-2i}$ is well-defined. This is true because  $e^z-2i=0 \Rightarrow |e^z|=|2i| \iff e^{Re(z)}=2$ which is impossible in $U$, therefore $f$ is analytic once is the quotient of two analytic functions. Notice that $\frac{1}{2}<r$ implies $C\subset U$.

Finally by Cauchy formula, $\int_{C} \frac{e^z}{z(e^z-2i)} dz=\int_{C} \frac{f(z)}{z} dz=2\pi if(0)\text{ind}(0,C)=\frac{2\pi i}{1-2i}$ considering that $C$ goes counterclockwise.